# Warning: Missing argument 1 for Template::error(),

Tags: php, arguments, warnings

I've got a problem.
I try to edit my content, but when I click on edit I get an error.
The error message I get is:

Warning: Missing argument 1 for Template :: error (), called in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ PassieCMS \ app \ cms \ edit.php on line 13 and defined in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ PassieCMS \ app \ core \ models \ m_template.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined variable: type in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ PassieCMS \ app \ core \ models \ m_template.php on line 89

here the codes of the 2 files

the edit page:

```
<?php

include("../init.php");

if(isset($_POST['field']))
{

}
else
{
    if(isset($_GET['id']) == FALSE || isset($_GET['type']) == FALSE)
    {
        $FP->Template->error();
        exit;
    }

    $id = $FP->Cms->clean_block_id($_GET['id']);
    $type = htmlentities($_GET['type'], ENT_QUOTES);

    $content = 'Conent here';

    $FP->Template->setData('block_id', $id);
    $FP->Template->setData('block_type', $type);
    $FP->Template->setData('cms_field', $FP->Cms->generate_field($type, $content), false);

    //load view
    $FP->Template->load(APP_PATH . 'cms/views/v_edit.php');

}
```

the m_template page

```
<?php

/*
    Template Class
    Handles all templating tasks - displaying templates, alerts & errors
*/

class Template
{
    private $data;
    private $alertTypes;

    /*
        Construtor
    */
    function __construct() {}

    /*
        Functions
    */
    function load($url)
    {
        include($url);
    }

    function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    /*
        Get / Set Data
    */
    function setData($name, $value, $clean = true)
    {
        if(clean)
        {
            $this->data[$name] = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data[$name] = $value;
        }
    }

    function getData($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->data[$name]))
        {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
        else
        {
            return '';
        }
    }

    /*
        Get / Set Alerts
    */
    function setAlertTypes($types)
    {
        $this->alertTypes = $types;
    }
    function setAlert($value, $type = null)
    {
        if ($type == '') { $type = $this->alertTypes[0]; }
        $_SESSION[$type][] = $value;
    }
    function getAlerts()
    {
        $data = '';
        foreach($this->alertTypes as $alert)
        {           
            if (isset($_SESSION[$alert]))
            {
                foreach($_SESSION[$alert] as $value)
                {
                    $data .= '<li class="'. $alert .'">' . $value . '</li>';
                }
                unset($_SESSION[$alert]);
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function error($type)
    {
        if($type == 'unauthorized')
        {
            $this->load(APP_PATH . 'core/views/v_unauthorized.php');    
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load(APP_PATH . 'core/views/v_error.php');   
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: A $type argument is mandatory for the error() method in your Template class; you're calling it without any argument: `$FP->Template->error();`

Comment: do you have an example? so I can see what you mean

Comment: `$FP->Template->error('THIS IS A TYPE');` or `$FP->Template->error('unauthorized');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a variable to your error() function as defined in `class Template`:

```
function error($type){ ... }
```

Comment: do you have an example? so I can see what you mean

Comment: I think Mark Baker's comment should be working for you: $FP->Template->error('unauthorized');